# How do I write a regex that captures the first non-numeric part of string that also doesn't include 3 or more spaces?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I want to extract from a string the first consecutive occurrence of non-numeric characters that do not include at least three or more spaces.  For example, in this string

```
str = "123 aa bb      cc 33 dd"
```

The first such occurrence is `" aa bb  "`.  I thought the below expression would help me

```
data.split(/[[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]]+/).first[/\p{L}\D+\p{L}\p{L}/i]
```

but if the string is `"123      456 aaa"`, it fails to return `" aaa"`, which I would want it to.

Comment: Why is the first occurrence `aa bb` and not just `aa`?

Comment: Check out rubular.com

Comment: We need more rules for this. Do you mean you need to "skip" the whitespace separated digit(s)  at the start of a string? Is "aa bb " OK as the first result (with no initial spaces) or are the initial spaces necessary?

Comment: @degant, It is ok if the first non-numneric portion contains up to two spaces, but not three or more.  So "aa bb  " is ok because it contains only a single space but notice that after the "bb" there is only two spaces.  If there were three following "bb," it woudl violate the rule.

Comment: How about: https://regex101.com/r/7mVS2v/1/ and just use the first match in every string?

Comment: Check http://ideone.com/ERQ1WN

Comment: Hey @Wiktor, if my string is "123 aa bb     cc", using your regexp, str[/^\d+(?:\s+\d+)*(\s*\p{L}[^\d\s]+(?:\s+\p{L}+)?)/] returns "123 aa bb," which is including a numeric token.  I wanted to get teh first non-numeric string of characters that did not also include 3 consecutive spaces.

Comment: You omitted the `1` argument that extracted Group 1 contents only. I do not find this question clear, sorry. You cannot rely on 3 spaces crierion since it can be before or after your needed match. You need something else. Note my example works as expected.

Comment: The rules in your question aren't clear. You should some more examples of input and expected output. Why does `123 aa bb cc` have to return `aa bb` and not `aa bb cc`. On what basis do you want to end the matching at the space after `bb`. Your rule says 3 consecutive spaces (which _aren't_ present at all)

Comment: @Wiktor, my bad, you're right.  Using that things do work as expected.

Comment: I have come up with a two step suggestion - http://ideone.com/Yubwmg. Remove all digits + spaces from the start. Then split with 3 or more whitespaces and grab the first item.

Comment: Oh ok, yeah that seems like a better idea as the previous suggestion didn't work after all.

Comment: In view of your first two sentences I interpreted it as meaning that you wish to identify the the first string that contains no more than two consecutive spaces and spaces at the beginning and end are to be retained, up to two spaces in each case. Otherwise, you would not have said the expected return value for the example is `"  aa bb  "`. Is that correct? In the comments you seem to suggest that if there are two spaces at the beginning of the matched string a solution can retain zero, one or two. If you are changing the question you need to edit it.

Comment: The reason your question is not clear stems from the fact that you framed it in terms of an example. Examples are generally helpful in clarifying questions, but they are not a substitute for a complete and unambiguous statement of the question, generally in words, something along the lines of the first sentence of my comment above. This is not just an SO issue (where many askers do what you have done), but examples rarely suffice when writing code specs or communicating with your colleagues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all digits + spaces from the start of a string. Then split with 3 or more whitespaces and grab the first item.

```
def parse_it(s)
    s[/\A(?:[\d[:space:]]*\d)?(\D+)/, 1].split(/[[:space:]]{3,}/).first
end

puts parse_it("123 aa bb      cc 33 dd")
# =>  aa bb
puts parse_it("123      456 aaa")
# =>  aaa
```

See the [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/6KMdlz)

The first regex `\A(?:[\d[:space:]]*\d)?(\D+)` matches:

- `\A` - start of a string
- `(?:[\d[:space:]]*\d)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `[\d[:space:]]*` - 0+ digits or whitespaces
  - `\d` - a digit
- `(\D+)` -Group 1 capturing 1 or more non-digits

The splitting regex is `[[:space:]]{3,}`, it matches 3 or more whitespaces.

Comment: `parse_it("123 aa bb      cc 33 dd") #=> " aa bb"`, but `"  aa bb  "` is desired.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That is not really important for OP.

Comment: You comment and the OP's reply concern only the number of spaces required at the beginning of the string that is returned.

Comment: I mean to say that there is no correlation between the expected result (stated as 2 spaces for the first string that has 6 spaces at that location) and the 3 or more spaces delimiter requirement. This part remains unclear and OP needs to edit the question to throw light on this.

Answer (score 3):

```
r = /
    (?:         # begin non-capture group
      [ ]{,2}   # match 0, 1 or 2 spaces
      [^[ ]\d]+ # match 1+ characters that are neither spaces nor digits
    )+          # end non-capture group and perform 1+ times
    [ ]{,2}     # match 0, 1 or 2 spaces
    /x          # free-spacing regex definition mode

str = "123 aa bb      cc 33    dd"

str[r] #=> " aa bb  "
```

Note that `[ ]` could be replaced by a space if free-spacing regex definition mode is not used:

```
r = /(?: {,2}[^ \d]+)+ {,2}/
```

Comment: You have [] in your match 1+ characters that causes strings with [] in them to match incorrectly. Try replacing bb with [bb]. You don't need to bracket the space inside a character class.

Comment: `[ ]` in a regex is a *character class*, meaning exactly one character in the class is to be matched.  `"a b".match?(/a[ ]b/) => true; "a[ ]b".match?(/a[ ]b/) #=> false`. Because I'm defining the regex in *free-spacing" mode (`/x`), had I merely entered a space it would have been removed when the regex is parsed. I could have instead used `\s` but whitespace includes tabs, newlines, etc., which might not be desired.

Comment: Never mind - I think my ruby tester did something funny to `[^[ ]\d]+`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this'd do it:

```
regex = /(?: {1,2}[[:alpha:]]{2,})+/
"123 aa bb      cc 33 dd"[regex] # => " aa bb"
"123      456 aaa"[regex] # => " aaa"
```

- `(?: ... )` is a non-capturing group.
- `{1,2}` means "find at least one, and at most two".
- `[[:alpha:]]` is a POSIX definition for alphabet characters. It's more comprehensive than `[a-z]`.

You should be able to figure out the rest, which is all documented in the [Regexp documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/regexp_rdoc.html) and [String's `[]` documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Comment: It does not match [`123      456 aaa`](http://rubular.com/r/EQIHXnPyLQ) (6 spaces between `123` and `456`).

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that condition.

Comment: In the OP's example the return value is to be `"  aa bb  "` (two spaces before `"aa"` and after `"bb"`).

Answer (score -1):

Will this work?

```
str.match(/(?:  ?)?(?:[^ 0-9]+(?:  ?)?)+/)[0]
```

or apparently

```
str[/(?:  ?)?(?:[^ 0-9]+(?:  ?)?)+/]
```

or using Cary's nice space match,

```
str[/ {,2}(?:[^ 0-9]+ {,2})+/]
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work.  If my str is  "123 aa bb     cc", the above returns "bb  ", but the first non-numeric portion of the string that doesn't include 3 spaces is " aa bb  ".

Comment: You are close: for `str = "123   aa      bb      cc    33 dd"` (4 spaces between `'aa'` and `'bb'`, which I can't show in a comment),  `str[/(?:(?:  ?)?[^ 0-9]+(?:  ?)?)+/] #=> "  aa    bb  "` (again, 4 spaces between `'aa'` and `'bb'`, but problem also occurs when there are 3 spaces). See my answer to see how you could modify your regex. In this case it's more convenient to use the method [String#[\]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) than [String#match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-match). Forth!

Comment: I wondered about having spaces at the end and beginning causing an issue. I think I fixed it. Though I do like your space 0-2 form.